# Generics: Type not applicable for arguments

Tags: java, algorithm, generics

Using generics the compiler should infer the type of the object T during runtime, however it is giving me a static violation as stated in the title and I can't figure out (using other questions) to fix this problem.

Here is my method:

```
public static <T> boolean linearSearchIterative(T[] array, T obj) {
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i].equals(obj)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is how I declare it in my main method:

```
int x[] = {2, 3, 5, 6, 1};
int y = 1;
System.out.println(LinearSearch.linearSearchIterative(x, y));
```

Comment: use Integer instead of int

Comment: Primitives aren't objects. You probably need an Integer[] and Integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Generics in Java work only with reference types, not with primitive types.**

Change the running code to:

```
Byte x[] = {2, 3, 5, 6, 1}; // or Integer
Byte y   = 1;               // or Integer
```

Comment: I used `Integer` and `int`, for some reason i didnt need `Integer` for the variable y, anyone know why?

Comment: Because of Java 5 feature called autoboxing.

Comment: Byte or Integer does not matter here. All the numbers fit into byte.